# Почему PHP очень долго работает?

Tags: php, apache, nginx, centos

Не могу понять по какой причине php скрипты очень-очень долго выполняются. Любая простая операция выполняется по 10 секунд.

Причем такие симптомы только при работе через nginx + apache, если же вызывать скрипт локально, то все нормально. При этом никаких проблем не было, но внезапно такая проблема возникла после обновления tzdata из репозитория: RPMforge.net

Подскажите куда смотреть и что делать?

Настройка Nginx 100% рабочая, т.к. работает ни на одном сервере уже не один месяц и ни разую не давала сбоев. Настройка Apache такая же как и Nginx.

ОС: CentOS 6.6

Удалил вот эту секцию и все стало летать:

```
ScriptAlias /munin-cgi/munin-cgi-graph /var/www/cgi-bin/munin-cgi-graph
<Location /munin-cgi/munin-cgi-graph>
       Options +ExecCGI
       <IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
               SetHandler fcgid-script
       </Ifmodule>
       <IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
               SetHandler fastcgi-script
       </IfModule>
       <IfModule !mod_fastcgi.c>
               <IfModule !mod_fcgid.c>
                       SetHandler cgi-script
               </IfModule>
       </IfModule>
       Allow from all
</Location>
```

Но как это связано с тормозной работой Apache + PHP?

Это я сильно ошибся, после удаления этой секции работало быстро не долго, сейчас опять по все вернулось на свои места — опять сейчас задержки могут быть до 30 секунд.

Comment: а содержимое скрипта предлагается угадать?

В целом - попробуйте откатить обновление и проверьте.
Также, попробуйте вытянуть минимальный код, который все воспроизводит. Также можно попробовать использовать профайлер - он покажет, какая часть кода тормозит.

Comment: код абсолютно любой, хоть `<?php echo 'test'; ?>` будет выполнять 5-10 секунд, хоть любой другой 5-10 секунд. Короче меньше 5 секунд не выполняется ни один php скрипт.

Comment: php подключается как модуль или как fcgi?

Comment: php подключается как модуль

Comment: Если я все правильно помню, то при подключении PHP как модуля инициализация PHP производится при каждом запросе, а это довольно дорогая операция даже без "плохих" расширений. Правда, последние правки указывают на то, что там вообще какая-то странная и трудноуловимая проблема.

Comment: Я сейчас вообще склоняюсь к проблемам на стороне провайдера. Очень странно все работает. Сейчас бывает выполняется все быстро, а бывает и по 30-40 секунд.

Comment: я бы в целях, чтобы снять сомнения, просто бы запустил на локалке, если работает без тормозов - ищем проблему уже у себя, если наоборот - звонок к провайдеру (хостинг и т.п.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема решена:

1. Долгая авторизация по SSH и невозможность пользоваться Интернетом с сервера решилась заменой DNS провайдера, оказалось DNS не рабочие.
2. Поменял формат логов Apache, т.к. выяснилось, что Apache даже с нормальными DNS тем не менее не может резолвить имена. Поставил чтобы писал в логи только IP адреса клиентов и тем самым скорость работы вернулась к прежней, даже стало работать чуть быстрее. Такие логи меня устраивают более чем, тем более что никогда не поздно преобразовать ip в имена посредством утилиты `logresolve`.

В целом проблема оказалась на стороне провайдера. О своих приключения отписался в службу поддержки, посмотрим что они решат. Замечу что ничего подобного никогда не наблюдалось у Amazon. Почему всегда такое происходит с русскими компаниями, остается открытым вопросом.